# If $A, B$ are non-singular square matrices of the same order and $(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}+B^{-1}$, then choose the correct option

Tags: matrices

> If $A, B$ are non-singular square matrices of the same order and $(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}+B^{-1}$, then the correct statement for every $A$ and $B$ is
>
> - A) $AB^{-1}=BA^{-1}$
> - B) $AB=BA$
> - C) $AB^{-1}A=BA^{-1}B$
> - D) $A=A^{-1}$ and $B=B^{-1}$

$$(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I\\\implies(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=I\\\implies I+AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}+I=I\\\implies I+AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}=0$$

Unable to proceed next.

BTW, a similar question exists [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062983/let-a-b-be-n-times-n-with-n-ge-2-nonsingular-matrices-with-real-entries-s).

Comment: I think you need $A+B$ invertible as well; else, consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}2& 1\\5& 3\end{bmatrix}$, $B=I$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now post-multiply by $A$
\begin{eqnarray*}
AB^{-1}A=-A-B
\end{eqnarray*}
and similarly post-multiply by $B$ ....

Answer (score 1):

For instance, try
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\, B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$Assuming the question is well-posed, only the third option checks out.

Comment: This, by the way, is a fine strategy for standardized tests and the like with multiple-choice answers. *Assume* the question makes sense (not always a valid assumption, but anyhow) and try and find an easy example or two that satisfies the conditions. Then you can just try the options with your example(s).