# Conditions for $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1}+B^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $n \ge 2$ and suppose $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$ matrices. Is there any criteria for $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ to hold?

Comment: Assuming they're all invertible in the first place, what happens if you multiply both sides by $A+B$, for example?

Comment: Related question: [Let $A, B$ be $n\times n$ with $n\ge 2$ nonsingular matrices with real entries such that $A^{-1} + B^{-1} =(A+B)^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062983/let-a-b-be-n-times-n-with-n-ge-2-nonsingular-matrices-with-real-entries-s)